Keeping dired minor modes on/off across buffers
I frequently toggle the two minor modes dired-omit-mode and dired-hide-details-mode in dired buffers. If I move into a new directory, dired creates a new buffer, and so these minor modes will (since I have them enabled by default) each be enabled, even if they were disabled in the buffer I’m coming from. That’s not the behavior I want. I’d rather that once I disable one of these minor modes, it would stay disabled while I move through new directories until I’ve explicitly reenabled it.
Is there a straightforward way to get that behavior?

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-dired-omit-mode dired-omit-mode
  dired-omit-mode
  :predicate '(dired-mode)
  :group 'dired)

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-dired-hide-details-mode dired-hide-details-mode
  dired-hide-details-mode
  :predicate '(dired-mode)
  :group 'dired)

Then you can use M-x global-dired-omit-mode and M-x global-dired-hide-details-mode to toggle the buffer-local minor modes in all dired-mode buffers.

Note that the :predicate support was only added in Emacs 28.1.  For older versions, you would make the TURN-ON argument a function which acts when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode) returns a non-nil value.

Great! define-globalized-minor-mode is just the function I needed.
